# Displaying data from MaasApi - object

Tags: php

As the title says I'm trying to display data here is my code

```
$mars_temperature = new MaasApi();
$data=$mars_temperature->getLatest();
var_dump($data);
echo $data['sol'];
```

error Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array  on the last line and here is var_dump:

```
object(stdClass)[3]
 public 'terrestrial_date' => string '2015-02-09' (length=10)
 public 'sol' => int 893
 public 'ls' => float 287
 public 'min_temp' => float -72
 public 'min_temp_fahrenheit' => float -97.6
 public 'max_temp' => float 2
 public 'max_temp_fahrenheit' => float 35.6
 public 'pressure' => float 890
 public 'pressure_string' => string 'Higher' (length=6)
 public 'abs_humidity' => null
 public 'wind_speed' => null
 public 'wind_direction' => string '--' (length=2)
 public 'atmo_opacity' => string 'Sunny' (length=5)
 public 'season' => string 'Month 10' (length=8)
 public 'sunrise' => string '2015-02-09T12:23:00Z' (length=20)
 public 'sunset' => string '2015-02-10T00:39:00Z' (length=20)
```

Update:

Here is also the code for API : https://github.com/dbough/MaasApi/blob/master/MaasApi.php

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to display data from this array I want to display for example $data['sol'] which didn't work or what's the easiest way to display max_temp min_temp etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access object properties, use the object operator: `->`.

```
echo $data->sol;
```

To echo the properties that you referenced in your comment, use:

```
echo $data->max_temp;
echo $data->min_temp;
```